# Linker error when compiling C++ code with CMake

Tags: c++, mongodb, cmake

I'm new to cmake and I'm trying to compile my c++ code with cmake to later on work with my **MongoDB local database**. The building of the files is working but when it comes to linking, I get an error from collect2: `"error: ld returned 1 exit status"` (normally shows error above line). I really think that the problem is in my CMakeLists.txt file, don't know what I'm missing or did wrong.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(documentations)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14")

include_directories("/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0")
include_directories("/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0")
include_directories("/usr/local/include/pistache")

find_library(MONGODB_LIBRARY mongoc-1.0)
find_library(BSON_LIBRARY bson-1.0)
find_library(PISTACHE_LIBRARY pistache)

add_executable(
    documentations
    myendpoint.cpp
    insert_doc.cpp
    find_doc.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(documentations ${MONGODB_LIBRARY} ${BSON_LIBRARY} ${PISTACHE_LIBRARY})
```

When using make in terminal

```
tolga@tolga-VirtualBox:~/documentations$ make
Scanning dependencies of target documentations
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/documentations.dir/myendpoint.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/documentations.dir/insert_doc.cpp.o
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/documentations.dir/find_doc.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable documentations
CMakeFiles/documentations.dir/insert_doc.cpp.o: In function `insert_doc(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, nlohmann::basic_json<std::map, std::vector, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, bool, long, unsigned long, double, std::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer>)':
insert_doc.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `insert_doc(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, nlohmann::basic_json<std::map, std::vector, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, bool, long, unsigned long, double, std::allocator, nlohmann::adl_serializer>)'
CMakeFiles/documentations.dir/myendpoint.cpp.o:myendpoint.cpp:(.text+0x1613): first defined here
CMakeFiles/documentations.dir/find_doc.cpp.o: In function `find_doc(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
find_doc.cpp:(.text+0x29): multiple definition of `find_doc(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
CMakeFiles/documentations.dir/myendpoint.cpp.o:myendpoint.cpp:(.text+0x1a8): first defined here
CMakeFiles/documentations.dir/find_doc.cpp.o: In function `find_doc_where(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
find_doc.cpp:(.text+0x208): multiple definition of `find_doc_where(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
CMakeFiles/documentations.dir/myendpoint.cpp.o:myendpoint.cpp:(.text+0x387): first defined here
CMakeFiles/documentations.dir/find_doc.cpp.o: In function `find_doc_where_single_field(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
find_doc.cpp:(.text+0x478): multiple definition of `find_doc_where_single_field(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
CMakeFiles/documentations.dir/myendpoint.cpp.o:myendpoint.cpp:(.text+0x5f7): first defined here
CMakeFiles/documentations.dir/find_doc.cpp.o: In function `find_doc_multiple_filters(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >)':
find_doc.cpp:(.text+0x74b): multiple definition of `find_doc_multiple_filters(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >)'
CMakeFiles/documentations.dir/myendpoint.cpp.o:myendpoint.cpp:(.text+0x8ca): first defined here
CMakeFiles/documentations.dir/find_doc.cpp.o: In function `find_doc_where_oid(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
find_doc.cpp:(.text+0xa7c): multiple definition of `find_doc_where_oid(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
CMakeFiles/documentations.dir/myendpoint.cpp.o:myendpoint.cpp:(.text+0xbfb): first defined here
CMakeFiles/documentations.dir/find_doc.cpp.o: In function `find_doc_offset(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, int)':
find_doc.cpp:(.text+0xcda): multiple definition of `find_doc_offset(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, int)'
CMakeFiles/documentations.dir/myendpoint.cpp.o:myendpoint.cpp:(.text+0xe59): first defined here
CMakeFiles/documentations.dir/find_doc.cpp.o: In function `find_doc_after_time(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int)':
find_doc.cpp:(.text+0xf4a): multiple definition of `find_doc_after_time(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int)'
CMakeFiles/documentations.dir/myendpoint.cpp.o:myendpoint.cpp:(.text+0x10c9): first defined here
CMakeFiles/documentations.dir/find_doc.cpp.o: In function `find_doc_between_time(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, int)':
find_doc.cpp:(.text+0x1195): multiple definition of `find_doc_between_time(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, int)'
CMakeFiles/documentations.dir/myendpoint.cpp.o:myendpoint.cpp:(.text+0x1314): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/documentations.dir/build.make:149: recipe for target 'documentations' failed
make[2]: *** [documentations] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/documentations.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/documentations.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
tolga@tolga-VirtualBox:~/documentations$
```

Comment: Firstly to learn creating Cmake file's go through the official tutorials- https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/

Comment: The compiler tells you that you defined symbols multiple times and thus you have linker issue. Create a header with function declaration and put definition only to single `cpp` file. Or make your functions inline.

Comment: Please add a [mre], the problem is likely in your code not cmake

Comment: if I delete my #include from my `insert_doc.cpp` and `find_doc.cpp` and have it all in my `myendpoint.cpp` file,  I get a lot of not declared. I use three libraries for the functions; `libmongoc-1.0`, `libbson-1.0` and `pistache`

Comment: This is clearly a C++ code issue (ODR violation, by the looks of it), post some relevant code snippets (including the relevant header). [Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for guidance.